# How to change the order of how $DISPLAY is allocated?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, gnome

Setup:  I have two X screens (i.e. DISPLAY=:0.0 and DISPLAY=:0.1 on the separate screens), running from different Nvidia graphics cards in a Ubuntu 10.04.

Q: I'd like to know how $DISPLAY is set for each of these screens.

Reason (perhaps there's a better way to achieve the same result): One of the monitors often turned off, this is DISPLAY=:0.0.  Popups (Authentication, info, volume control, etc.) from gnome always appear on this screen and I would like them to appear on the other one (DISPLAY=:0.1).  I figure if I can change the order that DISPLAY is set for each then gnome will put the popups on my favoured screen....or perhaps there is a gnome level solution?

Happy to provide more info, or to clarify my question.

Comment: anyone have any pointers?  ...i'm still stuck on this.

Comment: still stuck.....nobody???